# Laravel - Remember me not working as expected

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 5.5, and Laravel's built-in authentication system.

Confused about the Remember me option, this is my remember view

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary" style="margin: 0;">
        <input id="checkbox-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label for="checkbox-remember">Remember me</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When checked, it does add the remember_token token in the User database, so that part works. But it doesn't seem to 'remember' anything? All users whether they have a remember_me token or not can access the website straight away if they close the website/open it again. All users need to re-enter their email/password if they sign out and the remember-me box is not checked whether they have the remember_me token or not.

Tried both the file and the cookie session driver.

Struggling to see what exactly does it remember?

Comment: Are you using the standard controllers for logging in? Or did you make your own logic? Because you need to change the authentication logic in order to use the "remember me" option. [See the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#remembering-users)

Comment: Thanks @DouwedeHaan, but that seems to be in regards to manual authentication correct? I am using the standard controllers, built-in with Laravel. Nothing related to my own logic in regards to authentication, all out of the box.

Comment: Ah, I looked at the original files and your question again: It remembers the user. If you login and close your session (like, kill your whole browser) and then visit again, it will recognise the user and automatically log them in. If they logout, the remember token will be cleared. It doesn't actually put the credentials in the login form, if that was what you're thinking!

Comment: Looks like I had some different expectations from the Remember me option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remember me functionality from Laravel provides an automatic login for users who signed in with the remember me checkbox checked. This way users who closed their browser or killed their session don't have to login again.

Contrary to other websites (or some browsers, for that matter) who remember the credentials and put them in the login for you, Laravel doesn't do that.

As Laravel states in it's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#remembering-users):

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout.

Comment: Thanks, I am extending the functionality now remembering credentials.